# Ошибка при работе с RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, firebase-database

Подгружаю данные из БД `Firebase`, но `RecyclerView` падает с  ошибкой. Что я делаю не так?

**FirebaseActivity.java**

```
public class FirebaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private FirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter;

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);   //добавил эту строку

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);  //В этой строке ошибка

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("record");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        firebaseAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(this, databaseReference);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);

        firebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(firebaseAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseAdapter != null) {
            firebaseAdapter.cleanup();
            firebaseAdapter = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**FirebaseAdapter.java**

```
public class FirebaseAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Record, FirebaseViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public FirebaseAdapter(Context context, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        super(Record.class, R.layout.list_records, FirebaseViewHolder.class, databaseReference);
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(FirebaseViewHolder viewHolder, Record model, int position) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(model.getName());
        viewHolder.tvRecord.setText(model.getRecord());
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(model.getPhotoUrl())
                .placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
                .into(viewHolder.userPhoto);
    }
}
```

**FirebaseViewHolder.java**

```
public class FirebaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.textViewName)
    TextView tvName;

    @BindView(R.id.textViewRecord)
    TextView tvRecord;

    @BindView(R.id.userImageView)
    CircleImageView userPhoto;

    public FirebaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView); 
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.nikolai.game5nashki, PID: 4690
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nikolai.game5nashki/com.example.nikolai.game5nashki.FirebaseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.nikolai.game5nashki.FirebaseActivity.onCreate(FirebaseActivity.java:28)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**UPDATE**

Исправил как мне подсказали, но появилась другая проблема. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nikolai.game5nashki, PID: 11403
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:174)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6319)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5507)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5392)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5388)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2149)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1533)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1496)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:593)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3535)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3264)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3796)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:170)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6319) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5507) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5392) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5388) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2149) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1533) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1496) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:593) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3535) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3264) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3796) 
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079) 
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437) 
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743) 
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586) 
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495) 
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678) 
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171) 
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931) 
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107) 
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: jav
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте  `ButterKnife.bind(this);` после         `setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);`
Вы пометили аннотацией ваш `RecyclerView`, но не инициализировали `ButterKnife`

Comment: Спасибо, из-за своей невнимательности два часа не мог понять  в чем проблема.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, появилась другая проблема, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: StackTrace ошибки тот же?

Comment: Нет, StackTrace новый.

Comment: Так сразу и не понятно в чем дело. На инициализации адаптера падает. Надо дебажить